# Newer Whatsapp on device and play store

Tags: google-play-store, whatsapp-messenger

[image: version on whatsapp]
[image]

As is apparent from the images the version of whatsapp on my device is higher than the store version. I install and update from the store only. I have started getting messages on Whatsapp to update.

I have this on a Redmi Note 4X, running MIUI 9.

Comment: Possible. whatsapp version info on your device  will be higher than whatsapp version to download on website (website provides only stable version for download). This is for the case of beta users. I am currently on 2.18.12 where on website it shows 2.18.8.

Comment: @RahulGopi, I am not on beta and whatsapp is asking for update so...

Comment: I my case I cannot see whatsapp version both  in playstore app and through website login. shows this `varies with devices`.